# drop down menu not getting display none

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, frontend

I'm trying to create a dropdown menu like [wistia.com](https://wistia.com). But I cannot get this hover effect. I've put my code in a snippet below. When I hover on the main menu link the dropdown should appear. And when I hover outside of the dropdown it should vanish. Now it only appears when I hover on the menu but doesn't hide when I leave the menu.

```js
let dropdown = document.querySelector(".dropdown");
let chevron = document.querySelector(".main-link i");

function dropdownDisplay() {
  dropdown.style.display = "flex";
}
function dropdownHide() {
  dropdown.style.display = "none";
}
function chevronTransition() {
  chevron.style.trasform = "rotateX(0deg)";
}
```

```css
:root {
  --font1: roboto;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-family: var(--font1);
}
nav .container {
  width: 1340px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}
nav .container .links {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
nav .container .links .menu {
  margin-left: 32px;
}
nav .container .links .menu ul .main-link {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
nav .container .links .menu ul .main-link:hover i {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
nav .container .links .menu ul .main-link .dropdown {
  width: 1340px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  padding: 32px 0;
  cursor: initial;
  display: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
nav .container .links .menu ul .main-link .dropdown .cta {
  width: 300px;
  padding-right: 16px;
}
nav .container .links .menu ul .main-link .dropdown .cta h4 {
  color: #3ea9f5;
  font-size: 30px;
}
nav .container .links .menu ul .main-link .dropdown .cta p {
  color: #505050;
  margin-bottom: 32px;
  margin-top: 24px;
}
nav .container .links .menu ul .main-link .dropdown .cta a {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #3ea9f5;
  padding: 12px 32px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
}
nav .container .links .menu ul .main-link .dropdown .cta a:focus {
  outline: none;
}
nav .container .links .menu ul .main-link .dropdown .major {
  width: 150px;
}
nav .container .links .menu ul .main-link .dropdown .major ul li {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
nav .container .links .menu ul .main-link .dropdown .major ul li a {
  color: #505050;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav .container .links .menu ul .main-link .dropdown .sub-menu-links {
  display: flex;
}
nav .container .links .menu ul .main-link .dropdown .sub-menu-links .sub-menu {
  margin-right: 20px;
  width: 150px;
}
nav
  .container
  .links
  .menu
  ul
  .main-link
  .dropdown
  .sub-menu-links
  .sub-menu
  h6 {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #a7afba;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}
nav
  .container
  .links
  .menu
  ul
  .main-link
  .dropdown
  .sub-menu-links
  .sub-menu
  ul
  li {
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
nav
  .container
  .links
  .menu
  ul
  .main-link
  .dropdown
  .sub-menu-links
  .sub-menu
  ul
  li
  a {
  font-size: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #505050;
}
nav .container .links .menu ul .main-link i {
  font-size: 12px;
}
nav .container .links .logo h3 {
  font-size: 36px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="links">
          <div class="logo">
            <h3>WISTIA</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="menu">
            <ul>
              <li
                class="main-link"
                onmouseenter="dropdownDisplay()"
                onmouseout="chevronTransition()"
              >
                Product <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
                <div class="dropdown">
                  <div class="cta">
                    <h4>Product</h4>
                    <p>
                      Use our software and your videos to grow your business.
                    </p>
                    <a href="#">Start for free</a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="major">
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Integration</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class="sub-menu-links">
                    <div class="sub-menu">
                      <h6>CREATE</h6>
                      <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Recording</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Hosting</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Collaboration</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Management</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sub-menu">
                      <h6>PRESENT</h6>
                      <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Player</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Embedding</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Interactivity</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Channels</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sub-menu">
                      <h6>GROW</h6>
                      <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">SEO</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Subscribers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Reach & retarget</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Analytics</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li class="main-link">
                Learning Center <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
              </li>
              <li class="main-link">
                Podcasts & Series <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
              </li>
              <li class="main-link">
                About <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="buttons">
          <a href="#">Sign In</a>
          <a href="#">Get Started</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Can you set up a working sample with JSFiddle?

Comment: please share a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

You have not added hover state for the dropdown. You have to add

```
nav .container .links .menu ul .main-link:hover .dropdown {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add mouseover and mouseout events:

```js
let dropdown = document.querySelector(".dropdown");
let chevron = document.querySelector(".main-link i");

function dropdownDisplay() {
  dropdown.style.display = "flex";
}

function dropdownHide() {
  dropdown.style.display = "none";
}

function chevronTransition() {
  chevron.style.trasform = "rotateX(0deg)";
}


document.querySelector('#product-link').addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
  dropdownDisplay();
});

document.querySelector('#product-link').addEventListener("mouseout", () => {
  dropdownHide();
});
```

```css
:root {
  --font1: roboto;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-family: var(--font1);
}

nav .container {
  width: 1340px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

nav .container .links {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

nav .container .links .menu {
  margin-left: 32px;
}

nav .container .links .menu ul .main-link {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

nav .container .links .menu ul .main-link:hover i {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

nav .container .links .menu ul .main-link .dropdown {
  width: 1340px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  padding: 32px 0;
  cursor: initial;
  display: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

nav .container .links .menu ul .main-link .dropdown .cta {
  width: 300px;
  padding-right: 16px;
}

nav .container .links .menu ul .main-link .dropdown .cta h4 {
  color: #3ea9f5;
  font-size: 30px;
}

nav .container .links .menu ul .main-link .dropdown .cta p {
  color: #505050;
  margin-bottom: 32px;
  margin-top: 24px;
}

nav .container .links .menu ul .main-link .dropdown .cta a {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #3ea9f5;
  padding: 12px 32px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
}

nav .container .links .menu ul .main-link .dropdown .cta a:focus {
  outline: none;
}

nav .container .links .menu ul .main-link .dropdown .major {
  width: 150px;
}

nav .container .links .menu ul .main-link .dropdown .major ul li {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

nav .container .links .menu ul .main-link .dropdown .major ul li a {
  color: #505050;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav .container .links .menu ul .main-link .dropdown .sub-menu-links {
  display: flex;
}

nav .container .links .menu ul .main-link .dropdown .sub-menu-links .sub-menu {
  margin-right: 20px;
  width: 150px;
}

nav .container .links .menu ul .main-link .dropdown .sub-menu-links .sub-menu h6 {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #a7afba;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

nav .container .links .menu ul .main-link .dropdown .sub-menu-links .sub-menu ul li {
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

nav .container .links .menu ul .main-link .dropdown .sub-menu-links .sub-menu ul li a {
  font-size: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #505050;
}

nav .container .links .menu ul .main-link i {
  font-size: 12px;
}

nav .container .links .logo h3 {
  font-size: 36px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Navbar wistia</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/7e5d687fd9.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="links">
        <div class="logo">
          <h3>WISTIA</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="menu">
          <ul>
            <li class="main-link" id="product-link">
              Product <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
              <div class="dropdown">
                <div class="cta">
                  <h4>Product</h4>
                  <p>
                    Use our software and your videos to grow your business.
                  </p>
                  <a href="#">Start for free</a>
                </div>
                <div class="major">
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Integration</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="sub-menu-links">
                  <div class="sub-menu">
                    <h6>CREATE</h6>
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">Recording</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Hosting</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Collaboration</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Management</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class="sub-menu">
                    <h6>PRESENT</h6>
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">Player</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Embedding</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Interactivity</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Channels</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class="sub-menu">
                    <h6>GROW</h6>
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">SEO</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Subscribers</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Reach & retarget</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Analytics</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="main-link">
              Learning Center <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="main-link">
              Podcasts & Series <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="main-link">
              About <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="buttons">
        <a href="#">Sign In</a>
        <a href="#">Get Started</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <script src="./app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with only css
To change icon(**chevron**) in dropdown menu.

```
nav .container .links .menu ul .main-link:hover i {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
nav .container .links .menu ul .main-link i {
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
}
```

To hover the show dropdown contents

```
nav .container .links .menu ul .main-link:hover .dropdown {
  display: flex;
}
nav .container .links .menu ul .main-link .dropdown {
   display: none;
}
```

```css
:root {
  --font1: roboto;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-family: var(--font1);
}
nav .container {
  width: 1340px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}
nav .container .links {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
nav .container .links .menu {
  margin-left: 32px;
}
nav .container .links .menu ul .main-link {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
nav .container .links .menu ul .main-link:hover i {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
nav .container .links .menu ul .main-link i {
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
}
nav .container .links .menu ul .main-link .dropdown {
  width: 1340px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  padding: 32px 0;
  cursor: initial;
  display: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
nav .container .links .menu ul .main-link:hover .dropdown {
  display: flex;
}
nav .container .links .menu ul .main-link .dropdown .cta {
  width: 300px;
  padding-right: 16px;
}
nav .container .links .menu ul .main-link .dropdown .cta h4 {
  color: #3ea9f5;
  font-size: 30px;
}
nav .container .links .menu ul .main-link .dropdown .cta p {
  color: #505050;
  margin-bottom: 32px;
  margin-top: 24px;
}
nav .container .links .menu ul .main-link .dropdown .cta a {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #3ea9f5;
  padding: 12px 32px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
}
nav .container .links .menu ul .main-link .dropdown .cta a:focus {
  outline: none;
}
nav .container .links .menu ul .main-link .dropdown .major {
  width: 150px;
}
nav .container .links .menu ul .main-link .dropdown .major ul li {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
nav .container .links .menu ul .main-link .dropdown .major ul li a {
  color: #505050;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav .container .links .menu ul .main-link .dropdown .sub-menu-links {
  display: flex;
}
nav .container .links .menu ul .main-link .dropdown .sub-menu-links .sub-menu {
  margin-right: 20px;
  width: 150px;
}
nav
  .container
  .links
  .menu
  ul
  .main-link
  .dropdown
  .sub-menu-links
  .sub-menu
  h6 {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #a7afba;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}
nav
  .container
  .links
  .menu
  ul
  .main-link
  .dropdown
  .sub-menu-links
  .sub-menu
  ul
  li {
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
nav
  .container
  .links
  .menu
  ul
  .main-link
  .dropdown
  .sub-menu-links
  .sub-menu
  ul
  li
  a {
  font-size: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #505050;
}
nav .container .links .menu ul .main-link i {
  font-size: 12px;
}
nav .container .links .logo h3 {
  font-size: 36px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Navbar wistia</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/7e5d687fd9.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="links">
          <div class="logo">
            <h3>WISTIA</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="menu">
            <ul>
              <li
                class="main-link"
              >
                Product <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
                <div class="dropdown">
                  <div class="cta">
                    <h4>Product</h4>
                    <p>
                      Use our software and your videos to grow your business.
                    </p>
                    <a href="#">Start for free</a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="major">
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Integration</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class="sub-menu-links">
                    <div class="sub-menu">
                      <h6>CREATE</h6>
                      <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Recording</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Hosting</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Collaboration</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Management</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sub-menu">
                      <h6>PRESENT</h6>
                      <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Player</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Embedding</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Interactivity</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Channels</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sub-menu">
                      <h6>GROW</h6>
                      <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">SEO</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Subscribers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Reach & retarget</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Analytics</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li class="main-link">
                Learning Center <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
                <div class="dropdown">
                  <div class="cta">
                    <h4>Learning Center</h4>
                    <p>
                      Use our software and your videos to grow your business.
                    </p>
                    <a href="#">Start for free</a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="major">
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Integration</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class="sub-menu-links">
                    <div class="sub-menu">
                      <h6>CREATE</h6>
                      <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Recording</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Hosting</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Collaboration</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Management</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sub-menu">
                      <h6>PRESENT</h6>
                      <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Player</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Embedding</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Interactivity</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Channels</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sub-menu">
                      <h6>GROW</h6>
                      <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">SEO</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Subscribers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Reach & retarget</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Analytics</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li class="main-link">
                Podcasts & Series <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
                  <div class="dropdown">
                  <div class="cta">
                    <h4>Podcasts & Series</h4>
                    <p>
                      Use our software and your videos to grow your business.
                    </p>
                    <a href="#">Start for free</a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="major">
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Integration</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class="sub-menu-links">
                    <div class="sub-menu">
                      <h6>CREATE</h6>
                      <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Recording</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Hosting</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Collaboration</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Management</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sub-menu">
                      <h6>PRESENT</h6>
                      <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Player</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Embedding</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Interactivity</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Channels</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sub-menu">
                      <h6>GROW</h6>
                      <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">SEO</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Subscribers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Reach & retarget</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Analytics</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li class="main-link">
                About <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
                <div class="dropdown">
                  <div class="cta">
                    <h4>About</h4>
                    <p>
                      Use our software and your videos to grow your business.
                    </p>
                    <a href="#">Start for free</a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="major">
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Integration</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class="sub-menu-links">
                    <div class="sub-menu">
                      <h6>CREATE</h6>
                      <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Recording</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Hosting</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Collaboration</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Management</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sub-menu">
                      <h6>PRESENT</h6>
                      <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Player</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Embedding</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Interactivity</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Channels</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sub-menu">
                      <h6>GROW</h6>
                      <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">SEO</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Subscribers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Reach & retarget</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Analytics</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="buttons">
          <a href="#">Sign In</a>
          <a href="#">Get Started</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <script src="./app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```